# How to change label and ticks of a pgfplots colorbar?

Tags: pgfplots, labels, 3d

I have a 3d plot with colored surface and a `colorbar` made with `pgfplots`.

My probably related questions are:

How can I set the `label` of the `colorbar`?
What are the equivalents of `zticks` (positions of its ticks), and `ztick label style` (changing the format of the numbers)?

Thank you very much!

Comment: It's usually a good idea to post a small complete example document. That helps to clarify the question, and it saves others the work of having to come up with a test case.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

The colour bar is a full-fledged `axis` environment, so all the usual options are available (like `title`). The ticks in this case are `y` ticks, so you can set the axis label using `ylabel` and the tick label style using `yticklabel style`:

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.6}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    domain=-180:180,
    colorbar,
    colorbar style={
        title=Color key,
        ylabel=Z-value,
        ytick={-1,-0.75,...,1},
        yticklabel style={
            text width=2.5em,
            align=right,
            /pgf/number format/.cd,
                fixed,
                fixed zerofill
        }
    }
]
\addplot3 [surf] {sin(x) * sin(y)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: +1, in my case this resulted in an error `Dimensions too large`. But setting `xtick={150,200,250,300}` worked.